# Selecionar dados da base de dados dentro de outro while?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Eu tenho um calendário feito por mim, não muito bom, mas feito por mim, em que tem um while que cria quadrados, ou seja os dias, do mês atual. Até aqui tudo bem, mas agora eu gostaria que, se num certo dia tivesse um evento, ele mudasse a cor desse quadradinho, ou seja, adicionar uma class por exemplo.

Aqui tenho o código

```
    <table class="calen">
      <?php
      $at=0;
      $days = date("t");
      $atual = date("d");

      while($at < $days){
        $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE MONTH(data) = '".$mes_at."' AND YEAR(data) = '".$ano_at."'");
        $mos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        $dia=substr($mos['data'], 8, 2);
        $at++;
        if($dia == $at){
          $clic="with_event";
        }else{
          $clic="";
        }
          if($atual == $at){
            $atual1 = "atual";
          }else{
            $atual1 = "";
          }
        if($at%7 == 1){
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr>";
        }
      ?>
        <td class="calen_td <?=$atual1; ?> <?=$clic; ?>" data-dia="<?=$at; ?>" data-month="<?=$mes_atual; ?>"><?=$at; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
  </tr>
    </table>
```

Eu tenho 4 eventos inseridos, 2 para o dia 17, 1 para o dia 15, e um para o dia 1, mas só no dia 15 ele adiciona a class `with_event`. Tem alguma solução?

Comment: Um `while` que faz queries à base de dados provavelmente não é o que pretende, pois cria demasiado peso. Melhor será fazer 1 query que traz os dados todos e processa-los todos com um `while`.

Comment: @Isac Poderá dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginando que na tabela `eventos` o campo `data` é de um tipo de data, podemos logo obter a quantidade de eventos por dia alterando a consulta para utilizar um `GROUP BY` pelos dias:

```
SELECT DAY(data), count(*) as contagem from eventos 
       where MONTH(data) = $mes_at and YEAR($ano_at) = $ano_at group by DAY(data)
```

Com esta consulta construímos um dicionário para que possa de seguida ser utilizado na construção do calendário em html:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DAY(data) as dia, count(*) as contagem from eventos 
               where MONTH(data) = $mes_at and YEAR($ano_at) = 2017 group by DAY(data)");

$dias = Array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $dias[$row["dia"]] = $row["contagem"]; //acrescentar cada contagem da consulta
}
```

De seguida utilizamos este dicionario no ciclo/laço que cria os vários dias da tabela:

```
<table class="calen">
    <?php

    $days = date("t");
    $atual = date("d");
    $mes_atual = date("m");

    for ($at = 1; $at <= $days; $at++){ //for para ser mais simples
        if($at%7 == 1){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
        ?>
        <td class="calen_td <?=$at==$atual?'atual':''?> <?=isset($dias[$at])?'with_event':''?>" data-dia="<?=$at?>" data-month="<?=$mes_atual?>"><?=$at?></td>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Repare que troquei os `ifs` por operadores ternários apenas para ficar mais compacto na escrita.

[Exemplo no Ideone (com dias de exemplo forçados)](https://ideone.com/dN290n)

Resultado do html do Ideone interpretado no browser:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .with_event {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .atual {
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .calen td {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <table class="calen">
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="1" data-month="11">1</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="2" data-month="11">2</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="3" data-month="11">3</td>
        <td class="calen_td atual " data-dia="4" data-month="11">4</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="5" data-month="11">5</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="6" data-month="11">6</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="7" data-month="11">7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="8" data-month="11">8</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="9" data-month="11">9</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="10" data-month="11">10</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="11" data-month="11">11</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="12" data-month="11">12</td>
        <td class="calen_td  with_event" data-dia="13" data-month="11">13</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="14" data-month="11">14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="15" data-month="11">15</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="16" data-month="11">16</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="17" data-month="11">17</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="18" data-month="11">18</td>
        <td class="calen_td  with_event" data-dia="19" data-month="11">19</td>
        <td class="calen_td  with_event" data-dia="20" data-month="11">20</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="21" data-month="11">21</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="22" data-month="11">22</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="23" data-month="11">23</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="24" data-month="11">24</td>
        <td class="calen_td  with_event" data-dia="25" data-month="11">25</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="26" data-month="11">26</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="27" data-month="11">27</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="28" data-month="11">28</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="29" data-month="11">29</td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="30" data-month="11">30</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Uma vez que agora tem a contagem de eventos por dia pode até mostrar quantos eventos tem esse dia no calendário, alterando apenas o `<td>`:

```
<td class="calen_td <?=$at==$atual?'atual':''?> <?=isset($dias[$at])?'with_event':''?>" data-dia="<?=$at?>" data-month="<?=$mes_atual?>"><?=$at?>
    <?php if(isset($dias[$at]) && $dias[$at]>0) { ?> //se tem dias coloca no span
        <span class="dias"><?=$dias[$at]?></span>
    <?php } ?>
</td>
```

[Veja este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/f4b6Hu)

Que lhe dá o seguinte html:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .with_event {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .atual {
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .dias {
      background-color: gray;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
      position: absolute;
      top: -5px;
      left: 35px;
    }
    
    .calen td {
      padding: 20px;
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <table class="calen">
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="1" data-month="11">1 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="2" data-month="11">2 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="3" data-month="11">3 </td>
        <td class="calen_td atual " data-dia="4" data-month="11">4 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="5" data-month="11">5 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="6" data-month="11">6 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="7" data-month="11">7 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="8" data-month="11">8 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="9" data-month="11">9 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="10" data-month="11">10 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="11" data-month="11">11 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="12" data-month="11">12 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  with_event" data-dia="13" data-month="11">13 <span class="dias">2</span>
        </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="14" data-month="11">14 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="15" data-month="11">15 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="16" data-month="11">16 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="17" data-month="11">17 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="18" data-month="11">18 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  with_event" data-dia="19" data-month="11">19 <span class="dias">1</span>
        </td>
        <td class="calen_td  with_event" data-dia="20" data-month="11">20 <span class="dias">5</span>
        </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="21" data-month="11">21 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="22" data-month="11">22 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="23" data-month="11">23 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="24" data-month="11">24 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  with_event" data-dia="25" data-month="11">25 <span class="dias">1</span>
        </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="26" data-month="11">26 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="27" data-month="11">27 </td>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="28" data-month="11">28 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="calen_td  " data-dia="29" data-month="11">29 </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```